# google app script function does not return form response

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-php-sdk

in google app script i write following code to read response from google forms

```
function formResponse() 
{
    var form = FormApp.openById('form-id');
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();
    for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++)
    {
      var formResponse = formResponses[i];
      var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
      for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) 
      {
        var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
        Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
        (i + 1).toString(),
        itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
        itemResponse.getResponse());
      }
    }
  return formResponses;
 }
```

in google app script log has successful entry of what i expect.

in PHP i am using following code for call google app script.

```
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($request->input('code'));
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$service = new \Google_Service_Script($client);
$scriptId = 'MIQpTICu_Gobs7BEB-v3lHZZMYprHmXMAQrb';
// Create an execution request object.
$request = new \Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
$request->setFunction('formResponse');
$responses = $service->scripts->run($scriptId, $request); 
$resp = $responses->getResponse();
print_r($resp);
```

it's not get any form responses values

Comment: There seems to have been a recent change. make sure you are opening the form with the /edit ID and not the /viewform ID

Comment: @SpencerEaston i only give edit ID

Comment: Your code has a nested `for` loop, but then it returns `formResponses`.  The `for` loops are not putting the data into a different object.  Right now, the `for` loops are running, but they are effectively doing absolutely nothing to affect what gets returned by the function.  Are you familiar with `JSON.stringify(object)`?

Comment: yes thank you. yesterday i found the answer..thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

i return formresponses instead of returning array object.